# Android emulator renders without antialiasing after update

Tags: android, android-emulator, antialiasing

Today android-studio suggested me to update android emulator. After that, I realized that it becomes render fonts and shapes without antialiasing. Is it possible to get antialiasing back?[image]

[image]

Comment: Same problem here, on OsX Catalina & Android studio. Any tip on how to configure antialiasing properly? I read that in the past it was a known issue, which required to use Apple's JDK, but now it should be supported in Oracle's one i think!

Comment: Hi Artur! Did you ever manage to solve it? I've had this issue happening since I switched to a newer computer. I'm on Ubuntu now and was on Fedora on my previous machine. I've searched around and yours is the only post with the exact same issue I'm facing! Many thanks and best regards.